# Is there a way to save the current time + 1 hour or 1day or 1week to a DatetimeField using django view orm?

Tags: django

Is there a way to save the current time + 1 hour or 1day or 1week to a DatetimeField using django view orm?

for example

models.py

```
    dead_line = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, default=utc_tomorrow)
def add_todo_by_ajax(request):
```

```
    title = request.POST['title']
    dead_line_option = request.POST['dead_line_option']
    # print("dead_line_option : " , dead_line_option)

    if dead_line_option == "1h":
        print ("1h")
        # deadline =
    elif (dead_line_option == "4h"):
        print ("4h")

    elif (dead_line_option == "8h"):
        print ("8h")

    elif (dead_line_option == "1d"):
        print ("1d")

    elif (dead_line_option == "8h"):
        print ("1w")

    todo = Todo.objects.create(title=title, author=request.user, director = request.user)
    print("todo(insert result) : " , todo)
    user_update = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user.id).update(uncompletecount = F('uncompletecount')+1)

    return HttpResponse(redirect('/todo/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

this is answer that I find

```
if dead_line_option == "1h":
    print ("1h")
    dead_line = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)
elif (dead_line_option == "4h"):
    print ("4h")
    dead_line = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=4)

elif (dead_line_option == "8h"):
    print ("8h")
    dead_line = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=8)

elif (dead_line_option == "1d"):
    print ("1d")
    dead_line = datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=24)

elif (dead_line_option == "1w"):
    print ("1w")
    dead_line = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=7)
```